# Exception case: checking to see if the element already exists in an array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, exception

I'm currently learning c++. I got stuck in this little problem with the exception.

A program asks users to enter 5 integers in an array. I need the program to manage an exception that requests the input of an element again if it already exists.

Here is my code, I figured out the global structure, but the problem is if you enter 0 the program will throw out an exception "already exists", that's not the result I wanted. I know where this comes from, T[j] was not defined in for loop, but I don't know how to deal with it. Could anyone help me to improve it, please?  other solutions are also welcomed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){
int i=0,j=0;
int temp;
vector<int>T(5); 

do{
  try{
    cout<<"user input "<<(i+1)<<":";
    cin>>temp;

    //T[j]= 'a000000000000000000'; //I tried to define T[j], that's maximum I can do
    for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
      if(T[i]==T[j])
        throw(0);
    }
    
    T[i]=temp;
    i++;
  }
  catch(const int){
    cout<<"Error: value already exists, try again"<<endl;
  }

} while(i<sizeof(T)/sizeof(int));

for(i=0;i<sizeof(T)/sizeof(int);i++){
  cout<<T[i]<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you do a code walkthrough and tell me what happens in the last iteration of your `for` loop over `j`?

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of exceptions. Just check for a duplicate and prompt again.

Comment: Why not just store it in a std::set, then ask again if the element is already in the set?

Answer (score 1):

This line creates a vector which contains 5 ints. All ints in the vector are zero:

```
vector<int>T(5);
```

This line runs a loop. Since `i` is zero, it runs the loop one time, where `j` is equal to zero, because `j<=i` is true, because both of them are zero.

```
for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
```

This line checks whether `T[i]` equals `T[j]`, which it does, because `i` and `j` are both zero, and `T[0]` equals `T[0]`.

```
  if(T[i]==T[j])
```

This line throws an exception.

```
    throw(0);
```

Did you spot the bug yet? Maybe you *don't* want to run the loop where `j` is equal to `i`. Maybe you want to loop while `j<i` instead of `j<=i`. So if `i` is 5, `j` goes from 0 to 4 instead of 0 to 5, and if `i` is 0, the loop does not run at all.

Also, as Mark Ransom pointed out, this is wrong:

```
sizeof(T)/sizeof(int)
```

It should be

```
T.size()
```

Comment: There was an issue in my code when I was trying to run my code again. In fact, I made a confusion about the if statement in for loop "if(T[i]==T[j])", it is actually "if(temp==T[j])".  that's what I was trying to write. Regarding j<i, yes that was a great spot, thank you so much for your explicit explanation, I'll pay more attention to such details.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof(T)/sizeof(int)` would work for an array, but not for a vector.  You want `T.size()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't a requirement for the numbers to be output in the same order as they were input, a std::set (or std::unordered_set) would work well

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main()
{
    constexpr int NUMBERS_TO_READ{5};
    std::set<int> numbers;
    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        int temp;
        std::cout << "user input " << (i+1) << std::endl;

        std::cin >> temp;

        if (numbers.find(temp) != numbers.end())
        {
            //temp is already in the set
            std::cout << "Value " << temp << " already exists, try again!" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            //temp isn't in the set. add it.
            numbers.insert(temp);
            i++;
        }
    
    }
    while (i < NUMBERS_TO_READ);

    for (const auto num : numbers) std::cout << num << std::endl;   
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, there's a requirement for the number order. But it gave me more information, I didn't know "set" in c++. thank you.

Comment: @jovi another option would be to use the set for determining if the number has already been seen and then a vector for ordering (only insert into the vector the first time it has been seen), though it is slightly wasteful of space.